# The SGA1 version of Riemann's Existence Theorem is about analytic spaces. How does one relate it to topological covering spaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

In SGA1, Theoreme 5.1 (Riemann's Existence Theorem) states:

Let $X$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-scheme locally of finite type, $X^{\operatorname{an}}$ the associated analytical space. Then the functor which associates to a finite etale cover $X'$ of $X$ the finite etale cover $X'^{\operatorname{an}}$ of $X^{\operatorname{an}}$ is an equivalence of categories.

Here the notion of "analytic space" (espace analytique) is that defined in Serre's GAGA. Namely, it is a locally ringed space, locally given as the vanishing of holomorphic functions. As far as I can tell, in SGA the notion of etale cover of analytic spaces is simply flat and unramified.

However, Riemann's Existence Theorem is often cited as an equivalence of categories between etale covers of $X$ and **topological** covering spaces of $X^{\operatorname{an}}$. Thus, I am missing a step here. How does one prove an equivalence of categories between topological covering spaces of $X^{\operatorname{an}}$ and etale covers of it in the category of analytic spaces? Is there a reference for this? Is it obvious? Does hold even if $X$ is singular?

Comment: If $X$ is, say, a complex manifold, and $Y \to X$ is a topological cover, then $Y$ inherits a complex manifold structure.

Comment: True. I guess there are two issues I'm still unclear about. One is it is somewhat unclear to me why if $Y\rightarrow X$ is a priori a topological cover, the resulting map of analytic spaces is etale. But I guess that's a somewhat easy technical proof... The second issue is -- does this hold for $X$ singular? In that situation your argument no longer holds...

Comment: @Amy Even when $X$ is singular, a topological cover is a local homeomorphism, so surely you should still be able to lift the complex structure on $X$ to one on $Y$? Is this wrong?

Comment: @WilliamChen That's totally correct.

Comment: @WilliamChen: For any complex-analytic space $X$, the functor $(Y \rightarrow X) \rightsquigarrow (|Y|\rightarrow|X|)$ from finite etale $X$-spaces to finite-degree covering spaces of the topological space $|X|$ is an equivalence.  (By "etale" I mean "local analytic isomorphism".)  Full faithfulness implies the rest (as it permits to work locally on $X$!), and an $X$-morphism $Y' \rightarrow Y$ is a section to the finite etale $p_2:Y' \times_X Y\rightarrow Y'$, so a clopen in $Y'\times_X Y$ that maps bijectively onto $Y'$. Since $|\cdot|$ commutes with analytic fiber products (!), we're done.

Comment: @Amy: An "etale cover" is not the notion you intend; you need to impose a condition akin to being a covering space, whereas "etale cover" means "surjective local analytic isomorphism".  So you can focus on "finite etale" maps (where "finite" in the analytic setting is classified via coherent sheaves of algebras, in the style of the algebraic setting once one has the theory of coherent analytic sheaves in hand, as is taken for granted in  that discussion in SGA1; the book "Coherent Analytic Sheaves" provides such background, as do Seminaire Cartan lectures by Houzel).

Comment: @nfdc23 Why is that first sentence (of your first comment) correct?  It seems like that's the whole point of the question.

Comment: @BenWebster: The rest of my comment gives the proof!

Comment: @nfdc23: You said that "etale cover" means "surjective local analytic isomorphism", but I'm somewhat confused about what you meant. I was assuming that etale is defined for locally ringed spaces as being flat and unramified, and that SGA1 uses this definition of etale when it talks about finite etale surjection of analytic spaces. Are you saying that the definition I had in mind has the interpretation of being a "surjective local isomorphism"? Or are you just pointing out that in SGA1 he's talking about *finite* etale *surjections*, and not just etale maps?

Comment: How do you see the relationship, if you at all think that it's relevant, between flat unramified finite surjections among analytic spaces, and maps that are covering spaces? Are these really equivalent categories, or am I fundamentally misunderstanding something?

Comment: There is no good notion of "unramified" for morphisms of general (locally) ringed spaces, as it involves a notion of $\Omega^1$ specific to each setting (schemes, formal schemes, rigid-analytic spaces, complex-analytic spaces, adic spaces, etc.). In each setting it is a hard theorem that "flat + unramified" (+ locally of finite presentation in some cases) is equivalent to other concepts (such as an infinitesimal criterion, or local analytic isomorphism in the complex-analytic case), and those are collectively called "etale". My first comment proves the categorical equivalence you want.

Comment: And yes, I was also pointing out that the discussion there in SGA1 is focusing on finite etale maps, rather than general etale maps (but I forgot to require in my first comment that the finite etale $X$-space has surjective structure map onto $X$, in order for it to match with covering spaces having finite fibers on the topological side).

Answer (score 1):

As William Chen points out, a topological cover of a complex analytic space inherits a canonical analytic structure.  **Any** structure defined by being locally isomorphic to a particular ringed space is inherited under topological covers.  This just isn't interesting for schemes, since covers in the Zariski topology are not very interesting (are there any non-trivial ones?).

The interesting direction of this statement is when any étale cover is a topological one.  This is a famous statement, so famous it has a name: the inverse function theorem.  For real and complex manifolds, this theorem holds, so étale covers are topological covers and vice versa.  For complex analytic spaces...I'm not totally sure, but [this paper](http://www.math.purdue.edu/people/bio?user=wlodar&page=Preprints/Implicit.pdf) made me think probably not.  It states a version of the inverse function theorem for analytic spaces which sure didn't seem like it involved actually finding the inverse of a function, but people are free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What is your definition of "etale" in the complex-analytic setting?  The usual definition is "local analytic isomorphism", and there is an "inverse function theorem" allowing arbitrary singularities: a map of complex-analytic spaces $X \rightarrow Y$ is etale near $x$ if it is flat at $x$ and $x$ is an isolated reduced point in $X_{f(x)}$ (for smooth $X$ and $Y$, in case of an isomorphism on tangent spaces we get an isomorphism of completed local rings). The main content in the proof is to show that if $x$ is isolated in its fiber then $f$ is *finite* between opens around $x$ and $f(x)$.

Comment: In the link you give, Corollary 2.5.2 is the local structure theorem for analytic maps near a point isolated in its fiber, the "Grauert-Remmert theorem" on finite morphisms alluded to in the Introduction, and it has been known for a very long time (well-documented in the book of G&R on coherent analytic sheaves, for example; look up their notion of "locally quasi-finite" morphism).  The CM hypothesis there ensures flatness by Theorem 23.1 in Matsumura's book "Commutative Ring Theory". If you also require $x$ to be reduced in its fiber then it becomes what I called "inverse function theorem".